# Ignite :Remove data from cache on count of 10 put operation in cache

Tags: ignite

I have a json Object and i am putting it into cache by using a thread which calls for every 5 sec,i want to remove cache data after 10 put oration perform and put that data into third party database.how can i do this,which are the techniques to do this.if have a sample example please share.Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the cache then? It can only contain up to 10 records for a very short period of time. Can you explain your use case a bit more?

Comment: i am doing an assignment,I have to create a thread which produce data for every 5 sec and store into cache,when on cache,put operation calls for 10 times then it should automatically remove that data from cache and stored into third party database.I tried to do write behind operation using batch size but i am not able to find a simple code that how i can use batch size with write behind,if you can explain,please share.Thanks

Comment: Is it a student assignment? A `HashMap` seems to be enough here. Is it really necessary to involve a distributed cache in this task?

Comment: No,its not student assignment,actually we are working with ignite and get data from iot device,so for fast storing and putting in database we are using ignite

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar behaviour by using a [cache store](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store) with [write-behind](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#section-write-behind-caching) along with an [expiry policy](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies).

But given the number of records, that you want to keep in the cache, I would do something like this:

```java
private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;

private Map<K, V> batch = new HashMap<>();

public void addRecord(K key, V val) {
    batch.put(k, v);

    if (batch.size() == BATCH_SIZE) {
        flush(batch); // Write data into the database.
        batch.clear();
    }
}
```